# How to determine the sender of Broadcast Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have an application that is at the same time a broadcast sender and receiver of standard action android.intent.action.SET_WALLPAPER. I want to do some stuff only in a case when another application broadcasted this intent.

Is there any way to determine who initiated a broadcast in onReceive method of a BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

If you only want to do something when an action was broadcast by another app (i.e. not yours), I imagine it should be easy to determine that your app *didn't* send this broadcast, and therefore it was someone else..

Comment: of course, but in that way I have to use kind of timestamp/flag somewhere in my app - I don't explicitly send a broadcast, it is done by Android when I call setWallpaper.

Answer (score 6):

If all you care about is if it was sent by your app or not, what you can do is add an extra to the Intent every time you create one. For example:

```
broadcastIntent.putExtra('com.android.app.EXTRA_APP_CREATED', true)
```

Then, when you receive the broadcast, you can check

```
if (intent.getExtra('com.android.app.EXTRA_APP_CREATED', false) { ... }
```

To see if you created the intent.