# Android new outgoing call

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the sender of Broadcast Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755896/how-to-determine-the-sender-of-broadcast-intent)

I have applied new outgoing call broadcast receiver. It is working fine.

But I want to know that from which application user has dialed call.

i.e.  from default dialer or google voice application?

How can I know this?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge Android doesn't provide any means of identifying the source of any given broadcast. If this was your own intent you could add that information as an extra, but in general (including your specific scenario) I don't think you can find out where it came from.

Comment: It might be possible to do something hacky but that is not guaranteed to work in the long run. I would inspect the Intent received on both occasions at the debugger and check if there is something that can help distinguish between the two : an extra, a flag, a category,etc...

But this is clearly not a final solution.

Comment: @AndréOriani, the intent is sent by the system and the only extra it will have is the phone number being called, independent of the application doing the call.

Answer (score 0):

My first try would be to get source of broadcast or intent sending the broadcast. However, Android does not provide a way to know that and they even do not emphasize on that because it is usually the content of the broadcast that makes sense to the user.

If it was your own application sending the broadcast, it would be very easy as Michael suggested. You would add an extra that would indicate your broadcast source to the receiver. However, the only extra you would be able to get from OUTGOING_CALL intent is the number the call is being placed to.

Nevertheless, I have a solution in mind, which is not guaranteed to work and is purely theoretical. You are at your own risk here.

The idea is to check the most recently used application in your receiver and assume that the call is done via Google Voice if it is one of the recently used ones. This is due to the fact that we expect the user to be active on Google Voice as soon as the call is placed and your receiver intercepts that.

So in your receiver, you could do:

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
RecentTaskInfo task = m.getRecentTasks(3,0).get(0);
String nameofrecentlyusedapp = task.ComponentName.toString();
```

to check the most recently used application and even use get(1) and get(2) to read the two least recent ones to provide more flexibility.

Just give it a try and let us know if it works or not.

Comment: There is a note at the documentation for `ActivityManager.getRecentTasks(int,int)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRecentTasks(int, int)). It says :_"This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here.Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future"_

Comment: Yes, that's why I said he is at your own risk. He should try and see if it works or not...