# Android: detect which app causes screen to turn on

Tags: android

I have an app that keeps the screen off when calling via bluetooth. It's a long story but for more context please visit http://www.rejh.nl/callscreenoff (not trying to spam, it's just to avoid the "why would you build an app for that?!" question)

Anyway. I have a problem. Everything works fine except that my Moto X turns on the screen a couple of (variable) seconds AFTER I hang up which makes it hard to determine if my app should lock the device (it could be the user who, after the call, immediately pulls his phone out of his pocket and wants to unlock it).

What I'm looking for is a way to detect which app caused the screen to turn on. Since I'm using a broadcastreceiver to detect USER_PRESENT and SCREEN_ON it would be nice if I could get this info in the receiver. Is there some <s>data in the intent I receive about</s> way I can find out which app caused the <s>intent to fire</s> screen to wake up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use Intent.getPackage http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getPackage() ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think so. It says: "Retrieve the application package name this Intent is limited to". The intent I get is from the system (telling me the screen turned on/unlocked). I'll rephrase my question because I now realize this isn't completely clear. I need to know which app caused the screen to wake up :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3756013/1395437) it is not possible. The intent sender could put extras in the intent, which would give away the indentity of him, so your best bet would be either catching the intent in the debugger and inspecting the extras, or using an app for that, for example: [Android Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsInVrLmNvLmFzaHRvbmJyc2MuYW5kcm9pZC5pbnRlbnRpbnRlcmNlcHQiXQ..)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not looking to get it from the intent (per se). I just need to know which app caused the screen to wake up. The intent is sent by the system _because_ the screen wakes up but it's not the cause. Update: damn I thought I updated my question to make this clearer. Forgot one sentence. Will update.

Comment: I know, but there is probably no other way to find it. If it's the system, then it is already a problem, since you can't remove that or turn it off.