# Receive Broadcast only from specific package in android

Tags: android, security, package, broadcast, receiver

My Sender App will send it's version number to My Receiver App

***My Sender App's MainActivity (Initial Activity):***

```
package com.sender.app;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.putExtra("version", BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
   intent.setAction("get.sender.app.version");
   intent.setPackage("package com.receiver.app;");
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
   sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

=================================

***My Receiver App's Manifest:***

```
<receiver
  android:name=".receivers.BroadcastReceiver_GetSenderAppVersion"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="get.sender.app.version" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

***My Receiver App's MainActivity (Initial Activity):***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("get.sender.app.version");
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver_GetSenderAppVersion(), intentFilter);
}
```

***My Receiver App's Broadcast Receiver:***

```
package com.receiver.app;
public class BroadcastReceiver_GetSenderAppVersion extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

// IT SHOULD COME HERE, ONLY IF IT IS FROM SENDER APP PACKAGE (com.sender.app)

        if (intent.hasExtra("version") && intent.getStringExtra("version").length() > 0) 
            Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("version"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My Receiver App should print the Version number in Toast only if that is coming from Sender App with package id = com.sender.app

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I thought of is to send your package id within your intent.
In your sender app put :

```
 intent.putExtra("senderPackage","com.sender.app");
```

And then in you receiver app in onReceive do check:

```
if(intent.getExtras().getString("senderPackage").equals("com.sender.app")
```

Comment: This seems weird.
There are APK decompilers online which will show all the source code. So, anyone can put my sender app package name in extras, and send broadcast from their app.

Comment: I dont think there is a clean way to determine who sent you the broadcast. Please check:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755896/how-to-determine-the-sender-of-broadcast-intent